# What if, memory allocated using malloc is deleted using delete rather than free

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, free

I came across an issue which I could not resolve.

My question is, if I used `malloc` to allocate memory and then memory block is delete using `delete`?
The general thumb rule is

> If we allocate memory using **malloc**, it should be deleted using **free**.
>
> If we allocate memory using **new**, it should be deleted using **delete**.

Now, in order to check what happens if we do the reverse, I wrote a small code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class A
{
  int p=10;
public:
  int lol() {
    return p;
  }
};

int main()
{
  int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
    cout << a[i] << endl;
  }

  delete(a);
  // Works fine till here..

  A b;
  cout << b.lol() << endl;
  free(b); // Causes error.     

  return 0;
}
```

The error which I get is:

> error: cannot convert ‘A’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void
> free(void*)’

I am unable to understand why is this happening. Please explain.

Comment: b's type is class A. It is not a pointer. Therefore, you cannot free it.

Comment: To start with, you don't actually use `new` to allocate `b`.

Comment: You're passing object to `free` rather than pointer...

Comment: And if you correct the code, it will be *undefined behavior* trying to use `free()` on memory allocated by `new` (and the opposite), and anything could happen.

Comment: `delete()`/`free()` want a pointer as argument.

Comment: dont use malloc or free in C++. `new` and `delete` didnt invented in vain.

Comment: Ok, but I need to know why. I would request to please correct the code, as my code appears wrong.

Comment: Because these are facilities developed specifically for C++, to fit its idioms and patterns better. For instance, they call constructors and destructors for you.

Comment: If you don't follow the rules, bad things may happen. That's it, really. Follow the rules.

Comment: I rolled back the question. Please don't make material changes like that after you have a swath of answers to the original ersion. Also, why didn't you just ask why new!delete cannot be interchanged with malloc/free?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you call `delete` a pointer, the compiler will call the `dtor` of the class for you automatically, but `free` won't. (Also `new` will call `ctor` of the class, `malloc` won't.)

In you example, a char array apparently don't have a dtor, so delete does nothing but return the memory. That's why it's okay. (Or vise versa, new a char array and then free it.)

But there can still be a problem: what if `new` and `malloc` are borrowing memory from different heap manager?

Imagine that, you borrow money from people A, and return to people B later. Even if you are okay with that, have you ever consider A's feeling?

BTW, you should use `delete [] pArray;` to free an array allocated using `new[]`.

Answer (score 6):

The free function expects a pointer to memory allocated by malloc. The compiler is simply telling you that did not pass it a pointer, a fact that it can readily prove. I guess you meant to create an object with new and then call free on the address of that object. But you did not call new.

When you correct this you may well find the free succeeds but you should not read anything significant into any such success. You know the rules, they are clearly stated in your documentation. It is incorrect to do what you are attempting. The behaviour is undefined. There's little to be gained from an experiment like this. You won't learn anything about why the C memory management functions cannot be paired with C++ memory management functions.

The problem with your experiment is that is has no power. You can just show the outcome for one specific scenario. But these functions are designed to work across the board. How are you going to test every single possible scenario?

Never program using trial and error. You must always understand the rules and priciples behind what you do.

Comment: That is one reason. My motive here is to know why malloc and delete cannot be used interchangeably?

Comment: Your program will not lead you to any enlightenment. They cannot be interchanged because the spec says so.

Answer (score 5):

Your `b` variable is not a pointer, but a stack-allocated `A`. If you want to try this experiment, then you'd want to say

```
A* b = new A;
free(b);
```

I'm all for experimentation, but I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve here.

In C++, `operator new` doesn't just allocate memory, it runs constructors too. Similarly, `delete` runs destructors for you (taking polymorphic classes into account), as well as freeing the returned memory. On the other hand, `malloc()` and `free()` are just C library routines which (from a programmer's point of view) do nothing more than request a chunk of memory from the operating system, and then hand it back.

Now, for a simple, POD class with trivial constructors and destructors, you **might** be able to get away with mixing up C and C++ memory allocation, because there's nothing C++-specific to be done. But even if you do, what does it prove? It's undefined behaviour, and it probably won't work on another compiler. It might not work tomorrow.

If you use any C++ features -- inheritance, virtual functions, etc etc, it very definitely won't work, because `new` and `delete` have to do a lot more work than just allocating memory.

So please, stick to the rules! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't create `b` using `new` so you are not testing the intended hypothesis. (Also, the name of `b` is not a pointer.)

Anyway, `malloc`/`new` and `delete`/`free` work interchangeably only as long as their implementations are interchangeable. In simple cases and on simpler platforms this is more likely, but it's a risky bet in the long term or as a habit.

For example, the array form of `new`, when applied to a class with a nontrivial destructor, requires the implementation (compiler, runtime, etc.) to remember the size of the array so that `delete` may call the destructor for each array object. There is almost nowhere to put such information but in the dynamically allocated block itself, preceding the memory location referred to by the pointer returned by `new`. Passing this pointer to `free` would then require the memory allocator to determine the actual start of the allocation block, which it may or may not be able to do.

More generally, `new` and `malloc` may refer to completely different memory allocators. The compiler, runtime library, and OS work together to provide memory to your program. The details can change as a result of switching or upgrading any of these components.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation,](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

```
void free (void* ptr);
```

**ptr**::

> Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or
>   realloc.

And what you are passing is not a pointer, so it complains.

```
 A *b = new A();
 cout << b->lol() << endl;
 free(b); // Will Not cause error
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is **not** a *rule of thumb* that you should not mix new/free or malloc/delete.

Sure, it might be possible to use `free` to relinquish an allocation you obtained with `new` without a crash, but it is highly implementation/system specific.

Ignoring the fact that you're bypassing destructors or writing code that will corrupt memory on some systems, the more fundamental, more basic C++ consideration is really simply this:

malloc/free are global, system functions, while new and delete are *operators*.

```
struct X {
    void* operator new(size_t);
    void operator delete(void* object);
};
```

Sure - you can borrow a book from Amazon and return it to your local library: go there late one night and leave it on their front door step.

It's going to have undefined behavior, up to and including your getting arrested - and I'm talking about mixing new/free again here :)

Put another way: `malloc` and `free` deal with raw memory allocations, while `new` and `delete` deal with objects, and that's a very different thing.

```
void* p = new std::vector<int>(100);
void* q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
```

Answer (score 1):

Many good reasons have already been given. I'll add one more reason: the `new` operator can be overriden in c++. This allows the user to specify their own memory management model if they so desire. Although this is pretty uncommon, its existence is just one more reason why malloc and new, delete and free cannot be used interchangeably. This is for the reason described by @Patz.

Comment: looks like @kfsone beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

`free()` accepts a pointer.
You are passing an object (not a pointe) to free. That is why you are getting the error. If you make below change, your code works fine.

```
A *a = new A;
free(a);
```

Though the code above works fine, it will lead to a memory leak because `free()` doesn't call the destructor, which is responsible for freeing the resource(s) created by the constructor.