# Delete vs Delete[] in a custom operator in C++ (different than common delete vs delete[] questions)

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I define a class called MyNewDeleteAllocator and define custom new and delete operators for the class. This code has no bugs whatsoever and works perfectly fine. However, I have a question about line 29 of my code. It seems that changing "delete[]" to "delete" does not change anything in my code results.

I am aware of the difference between delete (single object when allocated by "new") and delete[] (array of objects allocated by "new[]").

I was wondering why interchanging delete and delete[] here on line 29 did not affect my results.

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Allocator class
class MyNewDeleteAllocator {
public:
    MyNewDeleteAllocator() {}
    ~MyNewDeleteAllocator() {}
    static void* operator new (size_t size);
    static void operator delete (void* p);
};

void* MyNewDeleteAllocator::operator new (size_t size) {
    void* p;
    p = malloc(size);
    if (p == NULL) {
        //Throw bad_alloc.
        std::bad_alloc exception;
        throw exception;
    }
    cout << "MyNewDeleteAllocator::operator new called with size_t " << size << endl;
    return p;
}

void MyNewDeleteAllocator::operator delete (void* p) {
    cout << "MyNewDeleteAllocator::operator delete called. " << endl;
    delete[] p; //THIS IS LINE 29
}


int main()
{
    MyNewDeleteAllocator* p = new MyNewDeleteAllocator; //Create MyNewDeleteAllocator object.

    delete p; //Delete MyNewDeleteAllocator object.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which one is line 29?

Comment: You are mixing `malloc` with `delete[]` - that's already *undefined behavior*

Comment: Line 29 is the last line of the delete operator implementation

Comment: @UnholySheep how am I mixing the two?

Comment: Your `operator new` returns a pointer to memory allocated with `malloc` - your `operator delete` tries to free that memory by calling `delete[]` on it

Comment: Aside: your comment and naming imply this is an [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator), it is not.

Comment: @UnholySheep how come "delete" also works?

Comment: @JohnLee Because behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: @eerorika How is it undefined? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JohnLee It is undefined because you `delete[]` something that was not returned by `new[]`. When behaviour is undefined, there are no guarantees whatsoever.

Comment: @eerorika should I be using "delete" instead then?

Comment: @JohnLee Did you allocate with `new`? If you did, then  yes. If not, then no.

Comment: @eerorika then how would I be deleting the p pointer if I shouldnt be using delete nor delete[] ?

Comment: @JohnLee You allocate with `malloc`. Therefore you deallocate with `free`.

Comment: @eerorika I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is not an allocator, or your name convention is wrong. In C++, an allocator allocates memory for a given type, not for raw bytes. More on that - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator

Second, don't mix `malloc()`/`delete` and `new`/`free()`. `malloc()` should be used with `free()`, `new` with `delete`, not the other way around. More on that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20488420/12979560

So, all you need to do is to replace `malloc()` with `new`. Also, when you use `new`, C++ will throw `std::bad_alloc` in case if it can't allocate the requested memory.